# How to set up the number of threads in a thread group by using the length of an array

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I have a user defined variable that contains several elements:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Is it possible to use the lenght of the above 'array' to pass as Number of Threads?
I tried using a beanshell function like this:
`${__BeanShell(vars.get("users_username").split(",").length,)}` but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As per [JMeter Functions documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

   > If a function parameter contains a comma, **then be sure to escape this with "\"**, otherwise JMeter will treat it as a parameter delimiter
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it is recommended to use __groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) instead of other scripting options/languages mainly because [Groovy performance is much better than alternatives](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Assuming all above you can dynamically define the number of threads as:

```
${__groovy(vars.get("users_username").split("\,").length,)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I did not see the reference to escape the comma.